# Why is my middle relay not picking up much traffic?

Tags: bandwidth, middle

I have been running a middle relay on a Linode VPS for many months now ([atlas report](https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/D44960365A3FC307EB6EF1A1E1A28985FD8484F7)).

My only bandwidth-relevant torrc setting is `AccountingMax`, set to 2 TB. The available bandwidth advertised by the provider is 1000 Mbps.

In practice, I don’t even reach 100 GB of traffic per month. Is this normal? Did I configure the node properly?

Comment: Are you sure the available bandwidth is 1000Mbps? The Atlas page is showing 797.92 KiB/s (about 6Mbps), and your bandwidth history is also very slow. Try running a speed test to see what speed your VPS actually has available.